# World of Supers

Tags: super-powers

In this alternate world, Super Powers are real and have been since the dawn of man. These super powers vary massively, from improved strength through to fire manipulation or telekinesis. If it has ever been portrayed as a super power in fiction, it is potentially possible to have in this universe.

Approximately 1% of humans have one or more super powers, and 1% of them are fully aware of their powers. (This could be due to never trying to breath under water for example, or your strength 'only' being 50% more than expected with a disinterest in body-building). Finally, 1% of that 1% (or one in a million) have the inclination and power set to be full time super heroes/villains. Despite research there is no known cause of super powers, as individuals seem to be born with them at random.

For the purpose of this question, we can assume that the existence of super powers on either side of a conflict cancelled each other out, thus alternate Earth is *very similar* to our Earth. Flying supers with laser vision may have been members of the Royal Air Force in WW2, but they were countered by German supers with similar abilities.

This question in particular focuses on every-day differences compared to our Universe. What would be different? My initial thoughts are the existence of psychic police detectives, a Super version of the Olympic games and Super battle property damage clauses in insurance contracts. What others would there be?

---

Edit: To tighten the scope, I'm looking for answers involving Businesses/Services specifically catering to Supers and those affected by them.

Any Super Power depicted in the Golden or Silver ages of Comic Books are possible and they occur at varying degrees of strength. A weak power of flight may require the user to concentrate very hard, or may do little more than lift the user a few feet of the ground and would definitely not be fit for a career Super. The recognised Supers will have stronger variants of the standard power, or have powers that are unmistakably super, even if weak.

Comment: Since we're talking about quite the broad question with a lot of personal opinion thrown in, my suggestion is that you go read the comic TOP 10, which deals *exactly* with this kind of question -the daily life of supers in their own city. Plenty of inspiration! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_10_(comics)

Comment: This looks like a particularly broad question, can you [edit] it to restrict the scope? As written it's likely to be closed.

Comment: This question is indeed very, very broad, but i think it is not necessary to be closed - (i am assuming it has already been flagged for that reason). Maybe you should refine your question to something more specific. Not something "here is a similar world with vastly game-changing differences, what large-scale differences would that cause?" Just ask yourself before raising a question "Can there be a 'right' answer to this question?". If it is a 'no', then it is likely people are going to flag it for one or another reason.

Comment: Even one of business, existing organizations, or legislature, is a broad area, (think about how much schooling lawyers need before they can even begin to practice law), you're going to need to restrict the scope much further before this question is a good fit.

Comment: @sphennings: Okay, I'll cut it down to just businesses for this question, and create  a series to cover the other aspects.

Comment: Can you be more specific about how superpowers work in your world? What powers are available, and how they work will be a significant factor in how they are integrated into everyday life.

Comment: Pick any mainstream superhero comic. That's what happens.

Comment: You would only have a total of like 7200 proper super heros spread out across the entire world. With that number it wouldn't be enough to warrant any normal business to cater to supers and it wouldn't really change the course of wars much because every hero would be so important. Any kind of business or service would probably be government related due to the potential danger and misuse of supers and would related to identifying, classifying and applying their powers in the best manner possible.

Answer (score 2):

### TLDR: There would be **more** supers

Every nation would try to increase this number of one out of  million.

### States would do everything to pump those numbers up

In your universe, 1% of humans have superpowers, 1% of them know it, and 1% of them use it.

1 out of 1 000 000 citizen will become super heroes. A little bit more than 300 for a country like U.S.A.

[image]

One Superhero alone is good, and even if he don't have that much direct effect, he could be use as propaganda. But thousands of superheroes, and you've got an army. The same can be done for other things (firefighters, police, medics, education...), so any nation have a huge incentive to increase these numbers, at each steps.

### Superheroes Studies

1% Of humans have super powers. Why? is it genetic? a mutation, but not hereditary? Do you have it since you're born or does it appear later? This questions will interest lot of scientists, and the answers will also interest countries.

### Superheroes Schools

The next thing to improve is the detection of superpowers. As in our universe, schools can be used to detect talents in various fields, I suppose your universe school will try to detect superpowers. At least, the most common super powers could be detected with sport and intelectual activities.

Once superpowers are detected, you can go to special school, where you can try to understand how your power work, and how use them at your best.

Basically, you detect super powers in primary/middle school, and go to specialised high-scool if you got any powers

### Superheroes recruitment

Let's say you want to do justice in real world. Would you go on the street, and try to do it by yourself? You would need equipment, contacts, you need to be known so if there is a problem, anyone can call you. And you need a way to intervene quickly. Also, what if other people try to do the same? damn, this would be a nightmare...

Or, you simply become a policeman. The state will give you equipment, have contacts, everyone know the police and can contact them quickly, they have enough policeman and infrastructure to intervene everywhere quickly...

For superheroes, it's the same. It's hard to impossible to do it by your own. But if you are part of something bigger, and we just gave you orders (and the means to do it properly), it's much easyer.

Sure, you can still be a rogue super hero, or work for a big company, but state can give you the best infrastructure and a work adapted to your super power.

Comment: Though more than likely, a lot of superhero powers would be completely and utterly useless, like say, the ability to grow your hair really quickly.

Comment: @Neil well, that depends a lot of the universe created by the OP. But an army of useless superheroes could be a funny story

Comment: @Neil, With that power, no one taking chemo would have to walk around bald.  Need to jump off a building?  Tie your hair to something and jump while growing it.  There are lots of ways of using that.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try and think of a couple weird/silly ones.

**An entire celebrity media are dedicated to superheroes.** Versions of Tiger Beat, US Weekly, People, what have you, all dedicated to Supers.  All the paparazzi, websites, massively invasive "journalism", turned up to 11. And that's why...

**Secret identities wouldn't last two weeks** Look at how fast the Internet tracked down Permit Patty and BBQ Betty, the Charlottesville Nazis, and pretty much every other Actual Monster we've seen in recent years.  Unless someone's wearing a full-face mask, even the smallest facial feature would be be enough for the detectives of the Internet to finger and dox heroes and villains in days.

Comment: And this is why, in my superhero series, heroes' identities are federal secrets. Somebody once deduced a superhero's identity, innocently leaked it onto the Internet, and... well, let's just say it didn't end well.

Comment: So, revealing one is a federal crime? Interesting idea, but even still thanks to the Internet, there's any number of ways to spread information anonymously. Super-Wikileaks, if you will.

Comment: If revealing the identity of a superhero is a crime, that needs to be listed among the premises in the Question.